# Reporting on multiple Selenium Webdriver job ran from Jenkins pipeline job

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, groovy

I have a pipeline job using Groovy script set up to run multiple tests in "parallel", but I am curious as to how to get the report(s) unified.

I am coding my Selenium tests in Java and using TestNG and Maven.

When I look at the report in target/surefire-reports, the only thing there is the "last" test ran of "suite".

How can I get a report that combines all of the tests within the Pipeline parallel job?

Example Groovy code:

```
node() {
    try {
        parallel 'exampleScripts':{
            node(){
                stage('ExampleScripts') {
                    def mvnHome
                    mvnHome = tool 'MAVEN_HOME'
                    env.JAVA_HOME = tool 'JDK-1.8'
                    bat(/"${mvnHome}\bin\mvn" -f "C:\workspace\Company\pom.xml" test -DsuiteXmlFile=ExampleScripts.xml -DenvironmentParam="$ENVIRONMENTPARAM" -DbrowserParam="$BROWSERPARAM" -DdebugParam="false"/)
                } // end stage
            } // end node
        }, // end parallel
        'exampleScripts2':{
            node(){
                stage('ExampleScripts2') {
                    def mvnHome
                    mvnHome = tool 'MAVEN_HOME'
                    env.JAVA_HOME = tool 'JDK-1.8'
                    bat(/"${mvnHome}\bin\mvn" -f "C:\workspace\Company\pom.xml" test -DsuiteXmlFile=ExampleScripts2.xml -DenvironmentParam="$ENVIRONMENTPARAM" -DbrowserParam="$BROWSERPARAM" -DdebugParam="false"/)
                } // end stage
            } // end node

            step([$class: 'Publisher', reportFilenamePattern: 'C:/workspace/Company/target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml'])

        } // end parallel
```

There is a little more to this code after this in terms of emailing the test runner the result of the test and such.

This works great, other than the reporting aspect.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use [ExtentReports](http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/java/) because it has a ExtentX server that allows to you report on multiple different test reports.

I used to use ReportNG but development on that stalled and so I don't recommend it any more.  It doesn't allow you combine reports anyway.

Other than that, you could use CouchBase or similar JSON database to store test results and then generate your own report from that information.

Comment: I actually am using Extent Reports as well. I didn't know about the ExtentX server for combining multiple reports. I will start researching how to do that and see if that will work

Comment: Let me know how it goes since I have not actually implemented ExtentX server but it appears it would work by looking at it.

Comment: Keep in mind that you could work around all this by having 2 separate test suites executed from within the same testng.xml suite file.  Then the ExtentReport that you get will show a aggregated report sorta like how ExtentX server will build for you.

Comment: I am not going to have the time I initially had to play with ExtentX, so for now, I just set up a Build Flow job to execute other individual jobs in parallel and then use the Build Flow Test Aggregator plugin to produce a combined report. I'm also publishing the HTML ExtentReport and all is well for now in that regard. I will definitely come back to ExtentX in the future. Looks interesting to say the least